# Using an array formula to add up several cells in another worksheet (using INDIRECT)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an Excel 2007 workbook. On one worksheet, I want to add up several regularly spaced values on another worksheet. I can easily do this with a very long sum formula without an array formula but it would be much simpler/nicer/easier to see what's going on if I could use an array formula. Below are a couple of my tries. Both seem to return only the first value out of the 8, instead of the sum of the 8. I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there a way to do this? Am I making a silly mistake?

Try Number 1:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Other Worksheet'!H" & {"12";"30";"48";"66";"84";"102";"120";"138"}))
```

Try Number 2:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'Other Worksheet'!H12"), {0,18,36,54,72,90,108,126},0))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, are your values separated by other number values or not ? 
If not, you can just use sum(other worksheet!h12:h138), it'll ignore text or null values found in between the figures ou want to add.
If yes, are these values identified by a label nearby ? For example, the word "total" in column G ? In this case you could use sum.if((g12:g138;"Total";H12:H138). It'll sum up only the values identified by the word "total"  on the left cell beside.

Comment: It looks like I can use the sumif suggestion, so +1 and thanks. I would still like to know how to use an array formula in general though.